# How to generate BPF executable from the assembly

Tags: llvm, bpf

I want to convert a BPF assembly into executable.
For example, I got

```
entrypoint:
    div32 r1, 1768515945
    exit
```

Can I get its executable? It should be loaded and executed by the bpf vm.

Comment: How did you get this assembly? What are you trying to do by reversing it?

Comment: If it is the assembly language that llvm understands (which I am not sure of, looking at your example), `llvm-mc` can do it, see [this example invocation](https://qmonnet.github.io/whirl-offload/2020/04/12/llvm-ebpf-asm/#assembling-to-an-elf-object-file).

Answer (score 0):

Each instruction is 64 bits. This should assemble to:

```
00:  69 69 69 69 00 00 01 34
08:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 90
```

The first instruction is from `BPF_DIV | BPF_K | BPF_ALU | (1 << 8) | (1768515945 << 32)`. The second is just `BPF_EXIT`. For more information, see [the kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/bpf/instruction-set.html). Note that `exit` expects `r0` to contain a return code, but you haven't explicitly set any. It should default to 0.